# Smooth Scaling of Image in java

Tags: java, swing

I created a button that extends Jbutton, I added to the button image but this not render smooth the image.
I try `getScaledInstance` But it's not working

This is orginal image:

[image: This is the origianl image]

That's how it really presents the picture:

[image]

```
public class Button extends JButton {
private Image image;


public Button(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
}
```

**Edit:**

I understood why it not rendered smooth the image.
I had to change the `drawImage` to `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);`

I run the code, sometimes it shows me the pictures and sometimes it shows me empty squares And that shows me errors in the console.

And only I move them with the mouse the pictures appear

[image]

Comment: This is not the cause of your problem, but… the last argument to `g.drawImage` should be `this`.

Comment: It can be `null` if you don't want an image observer.  Check out [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html)

Comment: @Ok, one more time.  I edited my answer.  I think this will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. It is pretty self explanatory.

```
public class CircleDisplay extends JPanel {

    final static int height = 500;
    final static int width = 500;
    Image img = null;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CircleDisplay();
    }

    public CircleDisplay() {
        Image img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO
                    .read(new File("f:yellowCircle.png"));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(
                JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        img = 
                img.getScaledInstance(50, 50,
                        Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        Button b = new Button(img);
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));

        add(b);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Button extends JButton {
    Image img;
    public Button(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(img,0,0,null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working, on JLable it does work but on Jbutton no

Comment: You can write all the code you wrote, maybe I'm missing something

Comment: I provided my test program. You will need to modify the path of the image.

Comment: The image looks fine but it doesn't cover the whole button

Comment: Your example has fixed it to look good, but I can't reduce the image. Look at my edit

Comment: You need to resize the button to match the scaled size.   Did you do the `setPreferredSize(`) on the button?  Did you size your `Button container` correctly?

Comment: Yes, let's talk about it in chat

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do it now.  And I have provided all the solutions I know.

Comment: You see my last edit? Sometimes it shows me the pictures sometimes writes an error

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why it needs to be so complicated.
I suggest simply creating an `ImageIcon` and setting the `JButton` icon.
Sample code:

```java
javax.swing.ImageIcon imgIco = new javax.swing.ImageIcon("path-to-icon-file");
javax.swing.JButton button2 = new javax.swing.JButton(imgIco);
button2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(imgIco.getIconWidth(), imgIco.getIconHeight()));
```

The last line of the above code ensures that the `JButton` size is the same as the icon size, since you implied that this is what you want in your comment to the other answer.

Comment: I had already suggested using the ImageIcon in an earlier edit.